How to implement VPN split tunneling in Android's VpnService to exclude certain IPs from the VPN tunnel?
I am trying to implement split tunneling in an Android VPN application. Specifically, I want all traffic to go through the VPN by default, but certain IPs should bypass the VPN and use the regular internet connection.
For example, in the Shadowsocks project, their VpnService implementation routes all traffic through the VPN. I need to modify it to exclude specific IPs or websites from the VPN tunnel.
Here's the shadowsocks VpnService code, the part I'm guessing should be modified is this:
https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-android/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/github/shadowsocks/bg/VpnService.kt
when (profile.route) {
    Acl.ALL, Acl.BYPASS_CHN, Acl.CUSTOM_RULES -> {
        builder.addRoute("0.0.0.0", 0)
        if (profile.ipv6) builder.addRoute("::", 0)
    }
    else -> {
        resources.getStringArray(R.array.bypass_private_route).forEach {
            val subnet = Subnet.fromString(it)!!
            builder.addRoute(subnet.address.hostAddress!!, subnet.prefixSize)
        }
        builder.addRoute(PRIVATE_VLAN4_ROUTER, 32)
        // https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149636790
        if (profile.ipv6) builder.addRoute("2000::", 3)
    }
}


We managed to implement split tunneling with the following approach:
For Android 33+, we used builder.excludeRoute to exclude the desired IPs from the VPN.
For versions below Android 33, we relied on builder.addRoute and included the required IP addresses calculated using the WireGuard AllowedIPs Calculator.

Here is a sample code:
class SplitTunnelVpnService : VpnService() {
    private var vpnInterface: ParcelFileDescriptor? = null
    private val excludedAddresses = mutableSetOf<IPAddress>()
    private var isRunning = false

    companion object {
        private const val VPN_ADDRESS = "10.0.0.2"
        private const val VPN_ROUTE = "0.0.0.0"
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        setupExcludedAddresses()
    }

    private fun setupExcludedAddresses() {
        // Add IPs or ranges to exclude
        excludedAddresses.apply {
            add(IPAddress("192.168.1.0", 24))  // Local ntework
            add(IPAddress("8.8.8.8", 32))      // Google DNS
            add(IPAddress("8.8.4.4", 32))      // Google DNS alt
        }
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        if (isRunning) return START_STICKY
        
        try {
            establishVpnConnection()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println("Failed to establish VPN")
            println(e)
            stopSelf()
        }
        
        return START_STICKY
    }

    private fun establishVpnConnection() {
        val builder = Builder().apply {
            setSession("Split Tunnel VPN")
            addAddress(VPN_ADDRESS, 32)
            addDnsServer("8.8.8.8")
            // Add default route for all traffic
            addRoute(VPN_ROUTE, 0)
            for (address in excludedAddresses) {
                try {
                    addRoute(address.ip, address.prefix)
                } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
                    println("Invalid route: ${address.ip}/${address.prefix}")
                    println(e)
                }
            }

            // optional, only works on specific package(s)
            // addDisallowedApplication("com.example.myapp")
        }

        vpnInterface = builder.establish()
        isRunning = true
        startPacketHandler()
    }

    private fun startPacketHandler() {
        Thread {
            try {
                handlePackets()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println("Packet handling error")
                println(e)
                stopSelf()
            }
        }.start()
    }

    private fun handlePackets() {
        vpnInterface?.let { vpn ->
            val inputStream = FileInputStream(vpn.fileDescriptor)
            val outputStream = FileOutputStream(vpn.fileDescriptor)
            val buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(32767)

            while (isRunning) {
                val length = inputStream.channel.read(buffer)
                if (length > 0) {
                    buffer.flip()
                    val packet = IPPacket(buffer)
                    if (!shouldExcludePacket(packet)) {
                        // Forward the packet in VPN
                        outputStream.channel.write(buffer)
                    }
                    buffer.clear()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun shouldExcludePacket(packet: IPPacket): Boolean {
        val destinationIp = packet.destinationAddress
        return excludedAddresses.any { excludedAddress ->
            isIpInRange(destinationIp, excludedAddress)
        }
    }

    private fun isIpInRange(ip: String, networkAddress: IPAddress): Boolean {
        val ipLong = ipToLong(ip)
        val networkLong = ipToLong(networkAddress.ip)
        val mask = (-1L shl (32 - networkAddress.prefix)).toLong()
        return (ipLong and mask) == (networkLong and mask)
    }

    private fun ipToLong(ip: String): Long {
        val parts = ip.split(".")
        var result = 0L
        for (part in parts) {
            result = (result shl 8) or part.toInt().toLong()
        }
        return result
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        isRunning = false
        vpnInterface?.close()
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    data class IPAddress(
        val ip: String,
        val prefix: Int
    )

    class IPPacket(buffer: ByteBuffer) {
        var version: Int
        var headerLength: Int
        var protocol: Int
        var sourceAddress: String
        var destinationAddress: String

        init {
            version = (buffer.get(0).toInt() shr 4) and 0xF
            headerLength = (buffer.get(0).toInt() and 0xF) * 4
            protocol = buffer.get(9).toInt() and 0xFF
            val srcAddr = ByteArray(4)
            val destAddr = ByteArray(4)
            buffer.position(12)
            buffer.get(srcAddr)
            buffer.get(destAddr)

            sourceAddress = srcAddr.joinToString(".") { (it.toInt() and 0xFF).toString() }
            destinationAddress = destAddr.joinToString(".") { (it.toInt() and 0xFF).toString() }
        }
    }
}

In manifest inside the service tag use this intent filter:
<action android:name="android.net.VpnService"/>


Could you explain in a bit more detail how the code you have written works?  Why do you need isIpInRange method and handlePackets? Are they necessary?

Yes, "excludedAddresses" are necessary.
You need to run the service
